I want to pass data from the UI (Angular) to API (ASP .NET Core)
Username and password are passed to the API when I debug it, but from UI it doesn't.
onSubmit() {
    console.log(this.loginform.value);
    var url = 'Auth/Login';
    this.Service.post(url,this.loginform.value).subscribe((user:any) => {
        if(user.status = true) {
            this.route.navigate(["/dashboard"]);
        }
        else {
        
        }
    });
}

This is the Api where I need to check the username and password.
In swagger it works fine, but the data that I enter in the UI returns "unknown error".
[HttpPost("Login")]
public IActionResult Login([FromBody] User login)
{
     if(login == null || String.IsNullOrEmpty(login.username) || String.IsNullOrEmpty(login.password))
     {
         return BadRequest("Email and Password is Required");
     }

     var user = AuthenticateLogin(login);

     if (user != null)
     {
         // Generate JWT token
         var token = GenerateToken(user);
         return Ok(new
         {
             message = "Logged In Successfully",
             token = token
         });
     }
     else
     {
         return Unauthorized(new { message = "Invalid Credentials" });
     }
}

private Login AuthenticateLogin([FromBody]User Logindetails)
{
    var Loginuser = _context.Login.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Email == Logindetails.username);

    if(Loginuser != null)
    {
        if(Loginuser.password == Logindetails.password)
        {
            return new Login
            {
                Email = Loginuser.Email
            };
        }
    }

     return null;
} 


Please show the definition of User and also what data is actually sent to the backend. Without knowing this there’s no way for us to suggest anything. Also AuthenticateLogin should not have [FromBody] since it’s not called from a web endpoint but that is not related to this issue.

Is the construction of your POST body what you expect?

What's the request makeup inside the request when you send the request?

You can attach a screenshot of the Network tab in the browser
